# How to hide table rows when data coming from the server is empty in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json-ld

How can i hide table rows when the data from the server is empty, i am using json-ld with angularjs.

This is my HTML Angular Template.

```
<tr ng-hide="'{{data['ts:versionID']}}'==''">
     <td>Value Set Version</td>
     <td>{{data['ts:versionID']}}</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-hide="'{{data['ts:effectiveDate']['@value']}}'==''"> 
    <td>Effective Date</td>
    <td>{{data['ts:effectiveDate']['@value']}}</td>
</tr> 
<tr ng-hide="'{{data['ts:releaseDate']['@value']}}'==''">
    <td>Release Date</td>
    <td>{{data['ts:releaseDate']['@value']}}</td>
</tr>
```

What i think is, {{data['ts:versionID']}} == '', will return true, if {{data['ts:versionID']}} == empty. And when condition is returning true, it should hide the ...

Comment: remove the brackets {{ }}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to parse the values:

```
<tr ng-hide="data['ts:versionID']">
```

should be enough for the first line (similar to the other two), making sure that the JSON response is stored in `$scope.data` (which I assume already is since you're outputting it in the `td`).

If the specified value if truthy (including the empty string - that's why I removed the comparison), it will be hidden.

Comment: the technique that you are suggesting, can be used with simple json, but the problem is, I am using JSON-LD. And when i try your technique, it gives me error because of ":" colon. I have tried alot, but no solution found yet.

Comment: Yes, that seemed like a problem right away, but I thought you had your way of parsing/dealing with it. I suppose you could iterate through the data once it is ready and make it more angular-friendly. But anyway, that's how the ng-hide is used.

Comment: Thanks, I tried again, the way you told. and it is working. :)